# Where to begin serious concurrent (multi-threaded, parallel ?) programming

Tags: multithreading, scala, parallel-processing, erlang

I would want to seriously begin multi-threaded/parallel/concurrent programming in *real world*. By that I mean like trying to solve *real* problems in parallel and concurrently and not just learning about low-level details of `pthread` or `MPI`, locks, races and the like or academic, text-book examples. Regarding low level mechanism of parallel programming, in fact I would rather not know anything about them and just stick with something more like Actor model :).

I have heard that some programming languages are inherently like what I am looking for and their paradigm  is to look at the problem at hand in a parallel (concurrent, multi-threaded, multi-processed) fashion and provide language level tools and constructs to implement the task in parallel (e.g. Erlang has a concept of `process` as a language construct?).

I fancy a language with a type system like that of Scala ... I know PHP very well and I used to do a lot of coding in C/C++. I have a working knowledge of Scala and Java and I can read Haskell but I'm not particularity proficient at it. I'm quite familiar with Functional paradigm and I'm willing to learn much more. I am also interested in high level theoretical discussions about parallelism/concurrency.

Comment: Node.js will help you.. hope

Comment: Solving real-world problems without understanding the real-world primitives upon which the high-level constructs are built is a shortcut that usually yields inexpert solutions.  If you're in a desperate hurry to deploy something, okay.  Otherwise, if you only put a hammer in your toolbox, all problems look like....

Comment: @RexKerr The way I understand it one can do well using Actor model without delving much into the details of how the Actor model is implemented in a certain platform. Kinda like learning Java instead of bytecode. But please by all means correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ashy_32bit - Well, why do you want to do things in parallel?  Maybe to do things fast?  Do you have thousands of processors at your disposal?  Probably not in a SMP configuration.  If not, you need to understand overheads of various different kinds of message passing or your performance will be horrible.  If you don't have thousands of processors, CAS-based solutions can be two orders of magnitude faster for some operations than e.g. Akka actors.  If you just want it to _work_ you can ignore the details.  If you want it to work _quickly_, you'd better pay attention.

Comment: @ashy_32bit - I should add that this goes for Erlang also: you can view most everything through the same framework, but you need to understand what the model handles well and what it doesn't, and what level of performance you can expect.  Used some ways, Erlang makes great use of your hardware.  Used other ways, you're better off with single-threaded Java.

Comment: @RexKerr I am more about *thinking* concurrently/parallel in direct contrast to thinking sequentially(?). Parallel and concurrent *feels* more natural and right to me but I'm not well versed in the field. To me it has nothing to do with locks or the like, it has everything to do with perspective and paradigm. Of course I don't wanna be an ignorant follower but the primary objective is to find a suitable language to express my way of thinking in code. At the moment I'm not very much concerned about the performance characteristics unless they are an indication of a mistake in thinking.

Comment: @ashy_32bit - What do you want to use concurrency _for_?  You can't just "learn concurrency" in the abstract _and_ use it for "real world problems".  That'd be like learning chef's knifes.

Comment: @RexKerr I see your point but again in my defense I would say it's like learning Functional Paradigm from a book that teaches you through giving examples of what are the real world value to each functional idiom you learn along the way. The chef's knifes example is more like learning about semaphores and not knowing what to do with them in the big picture. But I believe this is more like a speculation rather than a discussion :? perhaps I should just start to learn Erlang and see what I would encounter along the way ...

Comment: @ashy_32bit - It is certainly true that if you learn Erlang you will also learn things relevant to concurrent programming.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to mention first off that parallel != concurrent. They're closely related concepts, but *parallel* computation is distinction from *concurrent* computation in that *parallel* flows of control happen simultaneously while concurrent may be interleaved but could possibly be parallel. A fine hair to split, but one that's important to understand.

> ... provide language level tools and constructs to implement the task in parallel (e.g. Erlang has a concept of process as a language construct?).

An Erlang 'process' is a light-weight, memory isolated green thread. The language provides no shared memory constructs; data is passed between concurrent flows of control via 'messages'. Notice is said 'concurrent'. Erlang is explicitly designed to be a concurrent language and, it just so happens, will schedule some flows of control--which map 1:1 onto processes--in parallel. Erlang does *not* give you explicit control over scheduling, which is unlike the threading model.

It's hard to know what you're looking for--your question is rather broad--but any of the languages you've mentioned (except maybe PHP?) will allow you to exploit the multiple CPUs that are surely sitting in your computer. Pick several to focus on, expect to spend several years studying and go for it.

Comment: I think I'm after a language to teach me to *think* in parallel/concurrently and provides me the tools to code those thoughts rather than a language that teaches me the details of mechanisms that are used in the former language to implement the paradigm.

Comment: Then, `Erlang` is what you need... brother.